# Laravel/PHPUnit connecting to Docker test database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker test database, which is up and running, "ready for connections":

```
testdb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: ufr-mysql-test
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: workit_test
      MYSQL_USER: local
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: local
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    tmpfs: /var/lib/mysql
```

I can connect to it just fine vie Sequel Pro. My .env.testing file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=workit_test
DB_HOST=ufr-mysql-test
DB_PORT=3307
DB_USERNAME=local
DB_PASSWORD=local
```

I know I am correctly running phpunit in the testing file as I just overcame another issue with that and can `config('app.env');` in a test dumps out "testing", and yet I am hitting `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` when I run `vendor/bin/phpunit` in my app container. Am I missing something here? If I run `php artisan migrate --env=testing` in my app container I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = workit_test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE').`. I am manually clearing my the cache files in `bootstrap/cache/` (that fixes an issue where phpunit was running in the local environment rather than testing) and have run `source .env.testing`.

Comment: Two things I think could be the problem. Please correct me if I am mistaking. Firstly, the `DB_HOST` should be `testdb`, which is the address within your docker network. Secondly, the `DB_PORT` should be `3306`. Your code is calling the database from within the network, mapping `3307:3306` is meant for you local machine (outside).

Comment: Hmm, I can give 3306 a try, though my primary database is on 3306. I had tried testdb, but I don't that's correct as that is the service and I need to connect to the container. Also, when I connect to Sequel Pro successfully it is with 3307.

Comment: It might feel a little weird indeed. It depends on one important question I forgot to ask. Are you running your tests inside a docker container or on the host machine? If not use the suggestion of previous comment. If you run it on host machine the following values should be used `DB_HOST=localhost` `DB_PORT=3307` if no other mapping of hosts and ports is active.

Comment: Yeah, I am running them inside the container.

Comment: Alright, what fixed my situation is going with `DB_HOST=localhost` and `DB_PORT=3307` in my .env.testing, manually removing the `bootstrap/cache/*` and running `vendor/bin/phpunit` on my host machine rather than in the container. I think the issue that led me to try to run phpunit in my container was that `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan config:cache --env=testing` wasn't actually clearing the cache when running phpunit. Without clearing the cache my tests were being run in my local env. Thanks!